# How To Get List Of Apps A User Has Used

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was hoping to use the Graph API to retrieve a list of apps that the user currently has on their account - those that they are using or have used, and have not yet removed. This would be the same list as found by clicking App Centre and My Apps.

I'm not looking to get info about a specific application (yet; I don't know *what* app to look at, or how to get its ID).

This article: [How to get the List of Facebook Applications for a user using Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12881964/how-to-get-the-list-of-facebook-applications-for-a-user-using-graph-api)

seemed to be the right answer (and the OP certainly liked it), but for me, while it works, it returns an empty array - but I have about 20 apps (mostly games) listed on my profile, half of which are in favourites. I don't need to know which are in favourites; I simply would like to know what apps a user is interested in.

I realise this is considered sensitive information, but since I cannot find what string to use for the api() method, I can't tell what permissions I'll need; I currently ask for read_stream but since the call itself succeeds, I assume I have sufficient privilege.

I see that you can list the app *requests* using /me/apprequests, which suggests you should be able to retrieve the list of apps (that's where the requests come from, usually, except invites to new games) - but I can't find anything that seems right.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: @James - thank you. Unfortunately that also yields an empty array :(

Comment: ***Correction***: I misread what I was seeing. Both /me/accounts and /me/scores *did* return something - one item only, and that was the app I was testing from. That suggests that the article cited above was not talking about the right thing - it meant apps that the user is assigned to as creator or developer or similar. I need apps that the user is *using* (of somebody else's), not developing.

Comment: No, /me/scores will return scores for all the person's apps, but only if they've granted the appropriate user_games_activity permission.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can FQL be used to extract a list of all applications a user uses?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6589836/can-fql-be-used-to-extract-a-list-of-all-applications-a-user-uses)

Comment: @Igy - agreed, that is asking the same thing but the Q did not appear to be listed when I logged this Q. I also tried the FQL route, but hit the same wall.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to retrieve a full list of the applications that a user has TOS'ed.

As described in the comments to the OP, it is possible to deduce some of them from /[user]/scores assuming they have granted the user_games_activity permission.

Comment: I would +1 this as a valid answer, but I don't have enough rep yet. Sadly, you are correct. I have come up with another way to achieve something that will go half-way towards finding the info needed, and that is to monitor app requests and get app IDs from there and build a list over time. I hope FB decide to make it possible to get this info in the future as it can be used for some good, honest uses.